# How do I fill out a W-2 when applying for an ITIN?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, form-w-2, itin

When applying for an ITIN I’m sending a passport w-7 form and a 1040 form but in the 1040 form in the income section 7 they tell me to attach a w-2 form but I’m not a us citizen so I don’t have either an SSN nor an ITIN/EIN so how I’m I suppose to fill out a w-2 form? What do I do, do I just leave it blank? Thanks.

Comment: If you are not eligible for SSN, you are not eligible for employment in the US - hence you have no W-2 form. If this is a joint return, and your spouse is employed, then he/she would attach his/her W-2.

Answer (score 4):

The W-2 form is not something you fill out yourself. You are given a W-2 by your employer, and this form shows how much you were paid and how much tax was withheld from your paycheck. You include a copy of your W-2 with your tax return as “proof” that you have already paid some tax.

If you haven’t yet been an employee of a U.S. company with tax withheld from your paycheck and you haven’t received a W-2 from an employer, then you don’t need to include one with your tax return.